# How do I add random images to a web page with or without the help of backstretch in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

This is the code that I am using, but it is not working when I run it:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

             var lst_img = ["tab1.jpg",'tab2.jpg','tab3.jpg','tab4.jpg','tab5.jpg' 'tab6.jpg','tab7.jpg','tab8.jpg','tab9.jpg','tab10.jpg','tab11.jpg','tab12.jpg','tab13.jpg' 'tab14.jpg','tab15.jpg','tab17.jp','tab18.jpg','tab19.jpg'] 

           var loop = 0;
           var b = $('#img_container');
            var src = [];
        var len = lst_img.length;
       for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
            src[i] = $(#img_container).eq(i).attr('lst_img[i]');
            }

        setInterval(function() {


          // loop = (loop + 1) % len;
         $(b).backstretch(src, {
                     duration: 2000,
                     fade: 1750,
                     lazyload: true });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use backstretch? (The code you show has one obvious syntax error, `$(#img_container)` needs quotes. And `attr('lst_img[i]');` isn't going to do what you want *with* quotes.

Comment: i want to add images random and to display into div ,   so it should work near about like image slider....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two mistakes in your code first one is
`$('#img_container').backstretch(...)` 
 instead of this using like this what you doing is `$($('#img_container')).backstretch(..)`
and second one is

```
for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
    src[i] = $(#img_container).eq(i).attr('lst_img['+i+']');
    }
```

apart from this i am not sure about your code... just try this